# Is there an override on a UIView to know when it is actually shown on the screen?

Tags: uiview, ios4, event-handling, xamarin.ios

Is there a way with a UIView (or UIWindow) to override a method that will be called when the View (or Window) is first shown on the screen?

Note: I do not have a UIViewController in this application, and I would prefer to keep it that way if possible.

This would be similar to registering for the Activated event on a WPF Window?

I need to know when a View is actually showing on the screen before an action can be taken.

Also on iOS 4 with multi-tasking is there an override to get a notification for when your are "re-launched" so you can know the difference a first time a View is show and being shown again from multi-task switching?

Okay with MonoTouch C# or Objective-C examples/answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The override `public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)` in `UIViewController` will show when a view is shown on the screen.

With the multitasking there is an override in the App Delegate: `public override void WillEnterForeground (UIApplication application)` you could fire off an event (C#) or send off a `UINotification` via iOS Notification Center which the UIViews could subscribe to, telling them that the application has resumed from the background.

Comment: I do not have a UIViewController.  I only have a UIWindow with a single UIView as a subview.  It is a rather simple program, and a view controller wasn't required as there are no Widgets on the screen. I will be more specific in the question I guess.  It seems odd that the controller would be the one to get this event and not the view itself.

Comment: If there is no other way that to use a UIViewController then so be it but I feel like I am being forced to add unneeded layers to my very simple app, and being forced into MVC even if you don't have widgets, which means I have no Actions or Outlets.  I will mark this as the answer if I don't see a non UIViewController way of doing this posted soon.  As I fear your answer is the only way to do it.

Comment: I would still suggest using a `UIViewController` - for a couple of reasons. You'll get these useful overrides with regards to the state of the `UIView` (plus some other helpful overrides too!); also, if in the future the app does get more complex, most navigational tools in iOS use `UIViewControllers`.

Comment: Thanks.  It is just one of those Apple things that bugs me once in a while that I feel "forced" to do something I shouldn't have to.  I mean why should the state of one object be managed by another?  It is one thing to make MVC easy to do, it is another to cram it down your throat.  :)  Regardless thanks for pointing me where I needed to be.